# Example from search interval in date range

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a simple example of query from date to date. On Elasticsearch I have found some complex examples of query to handle data range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always refer documentation. In fact, queries looks complex but not actually.

Sample from documentation:

```
{
  "query": { //query handler
    "range": { //type of query
      "timestamp": {    //field Name   
        "gte": "2020-01-01T00:00:00", //greater than jan1
        "lte": "2020-01-21T00:00:00"  // less than jan 21                
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)